# Loop through Object and push into Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I am looking to loop the object and want to add those object in array in Javascript.

```js
//My Object:

var raw_data = {
  name: "Mike",
  age: "27",
};

var array_data = [];

//Then I loop through the object:

for (let [key, name] of Object.entries(raw_data)) {
  if (name !== "") {
    array_data.push({
      email: `${raw_data.name}`,
      password: `${raw_data.age}`,
    });
  }
}
console.log(array_data);
```

My out put is :

```
[
  { email: 'nang@gmail.com', password: '1234567' },
  { email: 'nang@gmail.com', password: '1234567' }
]
```

I would like expect to get only one insert:

```
[
  { email: 'nang@gmail.com', password: '1234567'}
]
```

Could you please help me how to get that?

Comment: The example you gave makes no sense. The input is a name and the output a email? The input is a age and the output a password? What?

Comment: your object has two keys, therefore your array must have two elements

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this, just push an object into an array and with the help of [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method loop through the array to replace your keys with your desired ones

```js
var raw_data = {
  name: "Mike",
  age: "27",
};

var array_data = [];
array_data.push(raw_data);

var new_array = array_data.map(item => {
  return { email: item.name, password: item.age };
});

console.log(new_array);
```